# restore to a previous git commit and reattach the head to it

Tags: git

Is this how to restore to a previous commit and reattach the head to it?

```
git log
git checkout 4bce33d    #restore to a previous commit
git branch -f master    #create new branch at head and force branch name to master
git checkout master     #attach head to master branch
```

This is only on local repository, there is no remote.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move head-branch to previous commit:

```
$ git status                    #make sure current directory is committed, or lose it
$ git log --oneline --decorate  #make sure there is a ref besides HEAD branch, or lose it
$ git reset --hard 9e5e64a      #move Head-branch to specified commit
```

Gaston pointed out a good reference.  The latest version is on http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified#The-Role-of-Reset

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to point `master` at a specific commit,

```
$ git checkout master # only if you're not already on this branch
$ git reset --hard 4bce33d
```

will work. Note that this resets both the branch pointer *and* your index and working tree. If you want to leave your working tree alone,

```
$ git reset --soft 4bce33d
```

won't change your files. Any differences between the new HEAD and your local directories will show up as "Changes to be committed".

Comment: That's right. The correct way to make any branch point to another commit is through `reset`. Here's a more in depth guide about how reset works: http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are ahead than your required commit then you can use this method
hit

```
git log
```

See how much commit you want to go back

then hit

```
git reset --hard HEAD~N
```

Will move you on N back commit.
N = 1,2,3 etc... It will move you N commit back.